# jQuery .click() firing ONLY at load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've searched on here plenty of places and I have not been able to find my situation, so here goes.

I am trying to avoid using the html inline onclick, so in doing so I am using the jquery click() like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(game());
});
```

When I use this, the function game() runs automatically and only runs and load time.

If I use the inline onclick, it works only when I click, and it works every time I click. Why is this?

Edit.. I swear I tried that.. oh well, It worked!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling the `game()` function and passing its result to `.click()`. Since its result is (presumably) not a function you have not actually set up a click handler at all. You need to pass a reference to the function, so remove the parentheses:

```
$("#start").click(game);
```

Comment: I will try and accept this answer tomorrow. Although for now I am not able to do so. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You are executing `game()` immediately by adding the parenthesis. If you want `game` to be evaluated on click then you need

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(game);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change it to this:

```
$("#start").click(game);
```

Answer (score 1):

Always more advisable to use **.on** & an anonymous function since it takes confusions like these out of the picture;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#start').on('click', function () {
            game();
        });
    }
);
```

What you're doing would be similar to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#start').on('click', function () {
            game();
        }());
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe youe need define game this way:

```
var game = function(e,...)

$("#start").click(game);
```

And remember the first parameter is the event object, passed from click function.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jquery function in a html element.

```
<canvas id="game" onclick="jqueryFunction()"></canvas>
```

In the jqueryFunction() make a if else statement
so if game is running : fire.

else if game not running :load game.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, although I don't really have any good reason to avoid it that I know of, but just trying different things out.